# How to connect Oracle Database from Jboss and register that connection in JDNI?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc, jboss

I've:

```
 public Connection getConnection() throws NamingException {

     Connection cnn = null;

     try {
         InitialContext init = new InitialContext();
         DataSource ds = (DataSource) init.lookup("java:/inventario");

         try {
             cnn = ds.getConnection();
         } catch(SQLException ex) {
             System.out.println("ERROR GETTING CONNECTION: "+ex.getMessage());
         }

     } catch(NamingException ne) {
         System.out.println("ERROR connect method: "+ne.getMessage());
     }
     return cnn;
 }
```

and execute test connection:  "ERROR connect method: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial"

Photo of Jboss configuration jdni:
[image]

Comment: Headline makes it more clearer now

Answer (score 0):

The above code returns connection successfully.Check with your jndi configuration of server.Sample wildfly config as below

```
 <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/MSSQLDS" pool-name="MSSQLDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.xx.xxx:1521/xxx.SERVER</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5000</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>xxxx</user-name>
                        <password>xxxx</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```